# Convert array key from string to int of same value

Tags: php, arrays

I have a a vaery large array which is parsed to my php script in json form. I would like to convert the keys from string to integer. The keys are serial numbers so i can't just use `array_values`. Currently i do it like this but would much prefer a solution that didn't involve a loop.

Example Array after json decode before int conversion:

```
array (
    '123' => 'my text',
    '223' => 'my text too',
    '183' => 'my text foo',
    '103' => 'my text doo',
    // more array items
);
```

Example Code:

```
$data = json_decode($_POST['json']);

$newArr = Array();
foreach ($data as $key => $val) {
    $ref = (int)$key;
    newArr[$ref] = $key; 
}
```

Comment: Are you sure they are just integers?

Answer (score 4):

```
$arr = array (
    '123' => 'my text',
    '223' => 'my text too',
    '183' => 'my text foo',
    '103' => 'my text doo'
);

$newArray = array_combine(array_map('intval', array_keys($arr)), array_values($arr));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this!

```
$test = array (
    '123' => 'my text',
    '223' => 'my text too',
    '183' => 'my text foo',
    '103' => 'my text doo',
    // more array items
);

$newArr = array_combine(array_keys($test), array_keys($test));
```

:)

Answer (score 0):

If you have the source function via which the JSON encodes, just add 
 `json_encode($data, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK)`
This will force the key fields in JSON to int (if int key field exist)